# Bake Action causes Animation to disappear

Tags: animation, baking, constraints, graph-editor, motion-capture

I am trying to bake the global translation and rotation of this bone that I have parented to the foot of this character that has motion capture animation on it. [image: Picture of character's foot and IK bone.]

I want to bake the values so that I can convert the foot to IK and hide the rest of the bones but whenever I hit the "bake action" button my animation disappears and there is only one keyframe of the starting pose that I am on in the timeline.

Here is a gif of before the action is baked[image]

Now I bake it.
[image]

And there is no more animation.

[image]

Thank you for helping me the people on this site are the true reason artists can create amazing things.

And here's the file (before I bake)
[image]

Comment: What is the name of the bone you are trying to bake?  It looks like mixamorig.LeftFoot.001, which has no local space animation.  What do you want to use that bake with?  As an IK target-- but as an IK target parented to what?  World?  Root?  Armature?

Comment: "mixamorig:LeftFoot.001" is the name of the bone. Basically what I'm trying to do is bake the translation relative to the world by parenting it to "mixamorig:LeftFoot" and then baking it. This way I can then just use ""mixamorig:LeftFoot.001" as an IK bone. The main goal of this is to convert the leg into IK from FK.

Comment: Okay.  You're not getting its translation relative to the world, you're getting its translation relative to mixamorigLeftFoot, which is nothing.  The reason you're getting that particular translation is because it's parented to LeftFoot.  If you want it's translation relative to the armature (which is the same as relative to the world, in your file), leave it unparented, then bake.

Comment: @Nathan if it's not parented to the foot then won't it just stand still?

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to mention something.  Leave it unparented, but copy transforms or position (via bone constraint) from the foot.  Then it acquires that position, relative to the armature.

Comment: @Nathan Thanks, that worked if you want you can put the answer in the answer section and I can mark it as the answer

Comment: I'm not invested in that, just in you solving your problem, and if I make a real answer, I'll invite criticism I don't care to hear right now.  If you want to put in your own answer and mark it, I wouldn't be offended or anything.